# Extract tar archive with empty directories with php PharData

Tags: php, phar, archive-tar

I'm trying to extract a .tar archive by means of PHP.
I'm using such a code:

```
$phar = new PharData('test.tar');
$phar->extractTo('/home/user/newtest');
```

It works fine, but **if my archive contains en empty directory** it is not extracted by the mentioned code. So, if my .tar file has this structure:

```
user@computer:~/test$ tar -tvf test.tar
drwxrwxr-x user/user         0 2012-12-07 22:35 dir1/
-rw-rw-r-- user/user       798 2012-10-28 23:41 dir1/articles.txt
drwxrwxr-x user/user         0 2012-12-07 22:35 emptyDir/
-rw-rw-r-- user/user       834 2012-09-15 22:47 main.html
```

I get after unpacking:

```
user@computer:~/newtest$ ls -l
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 4096 Dec.   7 22:35 dir1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  834 Sep.  15 22:47 main.html
```

So, the empty 'emptyDir' **is not extracted**.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `test.tar` was created using `tar -cf test.tar ...` on the command line.  PHP's `Phar` library is meant to read `phar` archives, *not* `tar` archives.

The [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.fileformat.comparison.php) shows the differences between phar, tar, and zip.  Granted, PharData is *supposed* to work on tar archives, so you might want to [report this as a bug](https://bugs.php.net/report.php) to the PHP developers.

For now, if you want to extract a `tar` archive in PHP, you have three options:

1. Create the archive using the `Phar` library in PHP and then extract in PHP
2. Use [Pear's Archive_Tar](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.filesystem.archive-tar.extract.php) (which works on `tar` and `tar.gz` files).
3. Call `exec("tar -xf test.tar -C /home/user/newtest");` (which is **not** recommended, but will work)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This archive was created with PharData::adfFile and PharData::addEmptyDir functions. Using 'exec' functions is not an option for me as it's not safe.

Comment: you really should look int Archive_Tar.  PharData is very finicky, and I just don't like it

Comment: @cegfault Could you please tell me why is using exec() not recommended?

Comment: also, can someone please confirm if this is a bug? I experience the same phenomena with php 5.3.3.

Comment: @gen: `exec()` has major security concerns, not to mention the loss of portability.  You should be able to find a lot on google about it.  And seeing how this question and answer was from over two years ago, I can't confirm it's a bug, but if you're experiencing this on php 5.3.3, I suggest you fill out a bug report with PHP and let them diagnose it

Comment: @cegfault thank you for your reply; I tried to report the bug, but php seems no longer concerned about this version, so I couldn't eventually submit the report.